# How to get success or failure result notification through on activity result of Whats App message after sending?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am sending whatsapp message with the help of Accessibility and following code.

```
   numberlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            try {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) numberlist.getItemAtPosition(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtnumber.setText(numberlist.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                String suffix;
                suffix = "Thanks";

                PackageManager packageManager = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                Intent saif = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                String message;
                message = txtmessage.getText().toString() + suffix.toString();
                String phone = txtnumber.getText().toString();
                String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phone + "&text=" + message;
                saif.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                saif.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                if (saif.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(saif, 1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR WHATSAPP",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Contact not found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    });
```

The message is successfully delivered or failed I am using the onActivityResult.

```
        @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"Message Send",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Back to ..:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions that I would like help with.
(1) - If WhatsApp is created on the sending mobile number, the message send and the success message is received through a toast. But if the sending mobile number is not on WhatsApp, the message does not go, but still the success message is received through Toast.

(2) - If there is no WhatsApp on the sending mobile number, then a notification comes from WhatsApp that "this number is not on WhatsApp". How can we auto handle this notification (that you see following image) through accessibility ?
[image]

Comment: `the help of Accessibility` ? What is that?

Comment: Sorry for this, What I mean is that I am sending messages by auto clicking the send button of Whats App using the Android Accessibility  feature.

Comment: You did not explain what an -Android- Accessability feature would be. Further: if there is a send button in whatsapp then where would it send a message to?. And what does this have to do with your button that tries to send a message to whatsapp?

Comment: I think maybe you know less about accessibility feature of Android? We use Android accessibility feature to auto click any button.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#java

Comment: Never saw it. Thank for the link. Is your onActivityResult triggered now? Further my questions stay the same. Why would you click a send button in whatsapp if you start with your own button that sends a message to whatsapp,?

Comment: I am working on a project of an app in which the user will write a message, then by selecting the contact in the mobile and then click on the start button for sending message to those numbers, the Whats App messages will automatically start going to those numbers.

Comment: You have not answered my questions. Any reason?

Comment: I think you have answered the question, maybe you don't have any suitable solution for my problem. Thanks